# Trying to understand a weird example where only an empty act seems to silence a warning

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using React Testing Library to test a component and I've come across a scenario where the only thing that seems to silence the warning

```
Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
```

is by using

```
await act(async () => {});
```

Now, I'll admit that I don't fully understand what `act()` does and sometimes I'll try using different variations of `act()` and `waitFor()`, asynchronous and non-asynchronous, until the warnings go away, but this time I was unable to do it without using the empty callback, which feels wrong and I'm sure will fail in the future, so I'd like to better understand what's going on.

I've created a sandbox that exhibits the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-ben-kfxm7q.

A few notes:

- I think the most important thing here is that my component has an effect that loads some data on rendering and then it updates the state in such a way that will cause the effect to run again, because it depends on the same data, but the second time nothing will change on screen. I understand this may seem convoluted, but the truth is I need the effect to run when the data changes, which can happen outside the effect, for example, by clicking a button. Please try not getting to focused on this bit
- For some reason, the `<Tooltip />` seems important, even though we're not asserting on it in the tests
- The button is not important, I just added it to show how the `data` can change outside the effect, causing the effect to run again

This example may not make much sense, but please understand that I had to simplify my real component a lot to the bare minimum that still shows the warning. Ideally, I'm looking for a way to fix the test without having to modify the component, because changing the real component may not be so easy.

Comment: To be honest `act` is a bit of a mystery for me as well. I tried wrapping your render with act and use `screen.getByText` instead of the destructured version and it doesn't throw the warning anymore. But again, I don't quite know how or why it works... `await act(async () => { render(<MyComponent />); });` and then `await waitFor(() => { expect(screen.getByText("Data has loaded! The minimum is 1")).toBeDefined(); });`

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting notifies you that a `setState()` ran after you tried to render your hook and your test could potentially be flaky.

`act()` makes sure to wait for all `useEffect()` and state updates executions. Since rerenders and state updates are async, you need to await for them.

Examples:

- "my event calls `setState()`"
- "my promise, when it resolves, calls `setState()`"
- "I want to call an endpoint onMount and then run `setState()`".
- "Trigger an event which calls `setState()` that rerenders the hook that triggers `useEffect()` that calls `setState()` again that rerender the hook again which triggers `useEffect()` ... and so on"

the flow is the same: async code -> `setState()`.

"Sometimes" the error is silenced because your test is inside a promise which you are not awaiting for.

```
it(async () => {
  // No "await" used inside here
})
```

When testing `async` stuff always use `try/catch` with `async/await` combining `expect.assertions(N)` ([Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectassertionsnumber), [Docs example](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait)). This makes sure that the test waits for the promise to fulfill/reject AND that `N` amount of `expect()` have been called.

If the test is **not** `async` but you are running async logic without awaiting, the test will not pass.

If the test **is** `async` but you are not awaiting, the test will pass.

I recently came across this, which could simply things ([Docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)):

```
// ...
// Wait until the callback does not throw an error. In this case, that means
// it'll wait until the mock function has been called once.
await waitFor(() => expect(mockAPI).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))
// ...
```